# Where does the linear system of equations come from in the Method of Undetermined Coefficients

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

I am studying for my Numerical Methods exam and I am having trouble with the Method of Undetermined Coefficients, specifically when it comes to obtaining the linear system of equations to solve for A, B, C.

First, I am given that $f''(x) = Af(x + h) + Bf(x) + Cf(x - h)$
(5.12)

Then I find the Taylor Expansion such that:

$$ 
f(x\pm h) = f(x) \pm hf'(x) \pm \frac{h^2}{2}f''(x) \pm \frac{h^3}{6}f'''(x) \pm \frac{h^4}{24}f^{(4)}(\xi\pm)
$$(5.13)

Then using the expansion of 5.13 in 5.12:

$$
f(x) = Af(x + h) + Bf(x) + Cf(x-h) = (A + B + C)f(x) + h(A-C)f'(x) + \frac{h^2}{2}(A+C)f''(x) + \frac{h^3}{6}(A-C)f^{(3)}(x) + \frac{h^4}{24}[Af^{(4)}(\xi_+) + Cf^{(4)}\xi_-)]
$$(5.14)

Equating the coefficients of f(x), f'(x), f''(x) on both sides of 5.14 we obtain the linear system:

$ A + B + C = 0 $
$ A - C = 0$
$ A + C = \frac{2}{h^2}$

I do not understand where we are getting the values on the right side of the linear system. I understand that we are supposed to equate f(x), f'(x), and f''(x) but this is how I understand it:

$f(x): A + B + C = B$
$f'(x): A - C = 0$
$f''(x): A + C = 0$

which is clearly not what the textbook gives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you used too many terms.

Couple different ways to get the same results.

$Af(x+h) = Af(x) + Ah f'(x) + A(h^2/2)f''(x)$

$Bf(x) = B f(x)$

$Cf(x-h)= Cf(x)-Chf'(x)+C(h^2/2)f''(x)$

---

$Af(x+h)+Bf(x)+Cf(x-h)=(A+B+C)f(x)+h(A-C)f'(x) +(A+C)(h^2/2)f''(x)$

---

Requires:

$(A+C)(h^2/2)=1$

$h(A-C)=0$

$(A+B+C)=0$

$A=C$

$Ah^2=1\implies C=A=1/h^2$

$B=-2A\implies B = -2/h^2$

$f''(x)=(1/h^2) f(x+h)-(2/h^2)f(x)+(1/h^2)f(x-h)$

---

Compare to an iterative method giving similar results via a restricted form of the binomial theorem.

$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

$f''(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f'(x+h)-f'(x)}{h}$

$f''(x)= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x+h)}{h}-\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}}{h}$

$f''(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+2h)-2f(x+h)+f(x)}{h^2}$

$x\to x-h$

$f''(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}$

---

Comment: I see what you mean by using too many terms, however I still do not understand where you are getting the right hand side values for the system of equations. For example, I see where you get (A + C)(h^2/2) (from the coefficient of f''(x). However I do not understand where you get the 1 from on the right hand side, for any of the equations.

Comment: You want to select $A,B, C$ so the  the coefficient of $f''(x)$ is 1, the coefficient for $f'(x)$ to be 0 likewise the coefficient of of $f(x)$ is 0. Coefficient of $f''(x)$ is $(A+C)h^2/2$ The coefficient of $f'(x)$ is $h(A-C). h(A-C)=0\implies C=A$. Plug that back into the coefficient for $f''(x) $ to get $(A+C)h^2/2\to (A+A)h^2/2=Ah^2$ A simplified expression for the coefficient of $f''(x)$. We want this to be 1, so $Ah^2=1\implies A=1/h^2\implies C=1/h^2$

Comment: Thank you. So for future problems of the same nature, should I always want the coefficient that we are approximating to be equal to 1? For example if I wanted to solve for f'(x) instead, would I begin with h(A-C) = 1?

Comment: I think so. Try it out for $f'(x)$ instead. I also think in general you might  the number of terms of the form   $f(x+mh)$  used to be 1 plus the order of the derivative you want to find. So, you'd ignore the $f''(x)$ terms  and $f(x-h)$ for finding c oefficient for the first derivative.